# Android Push Notifications are not displayed correctly

Tags: android, view, notifications, push, expandable

Previously, push notifications correctly displayed app information (**picture #1**). I tried to change a little notification design and now it has begun to hide the information inside, although it cannot be expanded (**picture #2**). Information will be visible only if I swipe the notification from left to right to select an action (**picture #3**). I can’t understand how this happened and what affects it, I only changed the design and returned it to how it was, but the problem did not disappear. At the same time, the notification is displayed correctly on the lock screen (**picture #1**).

[image: Push problem image]

I tried to return everything to its original state at the moment when everything worked correctly, I also tried to change the target version of Android between 33 and 34.

Comment: You need to provide your code so others can see what is your problem

Comment: Agreed. It's impossible to see what went wrong without seeing the code that was used.